# ADP Alter view in sql from access coding

Tags: vba, ms-access, adp

I have unique issue regarding ADP. I successfully linked SQL database to Access, but here are the issues. I want to update current view, I mean alter view with desired settings....

Is there any way, One can Alter SQL View Design from Access-VBA programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the some basic structure you can follow, in matter of ADP.

Create recordset using SQL database and assign it to form

```
Dim rsTest As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsTest = New ADODB.Recordset
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Test"
rsTest.Open sql1, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

And then you can assign that recordset to form.

But in case, when you want to perform any operation direct to SQL Server,

```
sql1 = "Update Test Set TF=1"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql1
```

In your case you can simply write SQL Command for alter view and simply say DoCmd.RunSQL sql1.

Hope that will help you.